# Is this transmission busted

Tags: transmission, clutch

This is a lancer evolution X MR with the Dual clutch TC-SST transmission:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Clutch_SST

The car will not move when in gear, the engine will rev but the car will not move forward under any circumstance.

Putting the car in Park will not keep the car from rolling (as if whatever is supposed to engage to lock the car in place does not) and moving the selector into park is accompanied by a terrible grinding sound (beneath shift lever)

The vehicle is not throwing any errors or codes so my local Mitsubishi dealership is useless.

Before I ship the car across country to one of the few places that advertises the ability to work on the transmission here I want to see if anything else can cause these issues.

Additional info:

The car will shift into all 6 gears, just wont move. Impossible to know the level of transmission fluid until it's pulled (no dipstick), but the trans was last services less than 10k miles ago. A visual inspection underneath and everything looks dry.

Perhaps the clutches are fried? But would that cause the car not to engage the parking gear? I would think I would have smelled that also.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you tell us anything about what lead to this? Has there been a progression of issues, or was this a sudden occurrence?

Comment: @CharlieRB It was a sudden occurrence. I was driving and went to shift into 2nd gear at about 20mph but the car would not shift and began to lose speed.

Comment: @Kisaragi You say it won't move forward, but will it move in reverse?

Comment: have you tried a different scantool? what are you using? a generic obd2 tool or evoscan? how many miles? have you ever had the trans serviced?

Comment: Using COBB's accessport which I believe is via obd2. Im just under 100k in miles and I've serviced the transmission and diffs every 15k miles since 30k